# Google CloudSQL Connection Error 10060

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Out of the blue our connection to our Google CloudSQL MySQL DB has stopped working. We are receiving a 10060 error when trying to open a connection (via Navicat).

Nothing has changed in our IP addresses or the security setup on Google's side of things. Connections to the DB weren't maxed out before this issue.

Has anyone else ever experienced this out of the blue? I can detail any more info if necessary.